# Fontawesome 5 Skip replace with SVG for some icons

Tags: svg, font-awesome-5

Is it possible to skip replace with SVG only for specific icons? for example containing some class? Or overwrite replace function to add this possibility. I have a case with 3rd party lib for linux dist icons, I would like to replace with SVG all icons coming from fontawesome packages but skip it for linux icons.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Javascript Version

```
<script src="/vendors/fontawesome/all.min.js"></script>
```

download the font awesome CSS file and library - from https://fontawesome.com/v5/download and use CSS version as

```
<link href="~/vendors/fontawesome/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```